# Error in angular moment

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I build android app and in my app have some search function with input type date. I try used parse input date from `2017-5-10T17:00:00.000Z` to `2017-5-10` with moment.angular. in search function work but it make my app error and wan't move to anothe page just stact in search page. I don't know where is error

this my html

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Start</span>
  <input type="date" ng-model="trip.start">
</label>
```

and this my controller

```
$scope.trip.start = moment($scope.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

and i add some srcin my index

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

please help me solve this problem

thanks

Comment: i think you should change order of JS files that is linked in your page

Comment: I am new to use angular moment and i tryexample from npm. I don't know change order of JS to another link

Answer (score 0):

the issue is mostly with date format. The date given is `2017-5-10T17:00:00.000Z` which is of format `YYYY-M-DD` and not a standard ISO format, hence moment is mostly not able to parse it. As per ISO the date should be  `2017-05-10T17:00:00.000Z`

Note: `.format` has nothing to do with input format, its for output.

Note: Cant comments hence adding this to answer: the order of JS is correct. `moment` is independent of `angular` hence it does not need to appear after `angular`.

**EDIT**

You can try below to get the date

```
    moment(Date.parse($scope.trip.start)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Comment: yeah your code work in my search page but still can't move to another page. in my issue is won't move to another page when i use angular moment

Answer (score 0):

moment($scope.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD") is not in Angular date object format.
As a work around you can use moment($scope.trip.start)._d.

So your code would be 
$scope.trip.start = moment($scope.trip.start)._d;

Comment: it work in my search but still  won't move to another page.

Comment: if you want to initiate any event then please use ng-change="onChange()" directive and define function in the controller

Comment: i already initiation if i remove moment angular my app can work corectly if i used moment to parse date input it just work in search page but error in my app